# Some borders are thicker in html table

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

My question is about the borders in html tables. Even using css to style it, some borders are thicker than others.

For instance, the usual approach found online is the following...

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

But some of the border lines are thicker than others. Is there a way to avoid this effect?

Comment: As a side note: Using tables to show tabular data is fine (and people accept it)

Comment: they're thicker because they are overlapping, can you post some code?

Comment: `border-collapse: collapse`?

Comment: Here is my table's CSS code :         font-size: 11px;
 color: #333333;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #666666;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 99%;
        padding : 10px 10px 20px 10px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin:auto;
        overflow: auto;
}

Comment: Even using border-collapse:collapse, some borders are thicker than other. I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Here is an example how my table is rendered ; note some lines are thicker than others : http://s24.postimg.org/t96yn5m5h/example.jpg

Comment: I have this problem in 2017-07: ugly gridlines, of variable thickness. Nothing to do with border-collapse or padding...  Did you find a solution?

Comment: I ran into this today. I'll post a new question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74999900/all-borders-are-equal-but-some-are-more-equal-than-others

Answer (score 3):

In CSS

```
table td {border-collapse:collapse}
```

In HTML

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: Here is an example how my table is rendered ; note some lines are thicker than others : s24.postimg.org/t96yn5m5h/example.jpg

Comment: Please post your code or create an example on Jsfiddle.com and I'll take a look.  A screenshot is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run your code on different browsers. Sometimes it may happen as your browser fails to render the table correctly.