# Table borders html css

Tags: html, css

I have a frame div and inside of this frame is a table with several columns and rows. For some reason, some of the borders are merging with each other.

```css
table {
  width: 50%;
  /* Ширина таблицы */
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Рамка вокруг таблицы */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* Отображать только одинарные линии */
}

th {
  background: #ccc;
  /* Цвет фона ячеек */
  padding: 3px;
  /* Поля вокруг содержимого ячеек */
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16pt;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* Граница вокруг ячеек */
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.brd {
  border: 5px black;
  /* Параметры границы */
  padding: 10px;
  /* Поля вокруг текста */
  border-style: inset;
  /*solid;*/
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div class="brd" align="center">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Why are some of the field borders inside of the table merging and getting bolder and how would I go about correcting this?

Comment: Is your browser zoomed or do you have any scaling occurring on your OS settings? That's the only time I see any inconsistencies with your borders on both FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to `border-collapse` and the fact you are adding border on all cells.

To avoid the problem you should adapt your cell border to get only 1 border:

```css
/*ADDED*/
table{
  border:0px;
  border-collapse: initial;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
td{
  border-bottom:0px;
  border-right:0px;
  border-collapse: initial;
}
tr > td:last-child {
  border-right:1px solid black;
}
tr:last-child > td {
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

### DEMO

```css
table { 
    width: 50%; /* Ширина таблицы */
    border: 1px solid black; /* Рамка вокруг таблицы */
    border-collapse: collapse; /* Отображать только одинарные линии */
}
th { 
    background: #ccc; /* Цвет фона ячеек */
    padding: 3px; /* Поля вокруг содержимого ячеек */
        
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td { 
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size:16pt;
    border: 1px solid black; /* Граница вокруг ячеек */
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
.brd {
    border: 5px black; /* Параметры границы */
    padding: 10px; /* Поля вокруг текста */
    border-style: inset; /*solid;*/
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

/*ADDED*/
table{
  border:0px;
  border-collapse: initial;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
td{
  border-bottom:0px;
  border-right:0px;
  border-collapse: initial;
}
tr > td:last-child {
  border-right:1px solid black;
}
tr:last-child > td {
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="brd" align="center">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked already: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025746/some-borders-thicker-in-html-table)

It seems that problem are related browser/OS. pixels isn't rendered correctly. On Mac screens it seems totally ok. Try different browsers.

As a trick you can use bolder table border and lighter color.